# A show about a woman released from prison who works in a hotel

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

I watched an American TV series that I can't remember its name. The drama is about a girl who just came out of jail (I don't remember why she was in the prison in the first place but I think it's something to do with her father but she is innocent). Anyway, she went to live in her grandmother's house with her brother and sister. I still remember that the actress was blonde but her sister was a redhead because she was adopted.

The girl starts to work in a hotel, I guess, and she fell in love with a rich guy who loved her back as well, then she discovered that his family owns the hotel and he is engaged to a girl named Elizabeth (I don't know why I only remember his fiancées name). He didn't like Elizabeth and was only with her just to please his mother.

**More info:**

- They were on an island, I think
- The guy had a friend who worked for him in the hotel and he kinda liked the blonde girl
- The guy also had a younger sister

I watched it like 5 or 6 years ago, I would say, but I can't remember on which channel exactly.

I usually type the plot in Google when I'm looking for a hint to remember the names of any movies or TV shows, but this one is completely vanished. I tried many times but there is nothing at all. I don't know why and really hope that someone will help me.

Comment: Sounds vaguely familiar. Was it a soap? Was it *from* 5-6 years ago or older than that?

Comment: i don't think it was a soap but im not sure. I saw it 5-6 years ago but yes I would probably say it was older than that but not to old though

Comment: Good thinking bumping it... Posted a possible match.

Answer (score 4):

God, my brain's slow, but I finally got there. ;) It's [Monarch Cove](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0829471/combined), a soapy Lifetime drama from 2006 based on the German telenovela [Bianca - Wege zum Gluck](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0432231/combined) from 2004.

> After being wrongfully convicted of her father's murder and subsequently spending six years in prison, Bianca Foster (Williams) returns home to a new set of family problems. Determined to help, she takes a job at a resort, only to become romantically involved with business's engaged heir (Hutchinson).

Bianca's blonde and her redheaded sister turns out to be adopted, she takes care of her sick grandma (Shirley Jones) and the heir is engaged to a woman called Elizabeth. Here are the first 10 minutes:

Comment: It's not my question, I just offered a bounty because the show looked interesting

Comment: @madmada D'oh, I totally forgot. Sorry about this! I'll delete my comment.

Comment: No problem and thx again for finding it